# When is the solution to a linear system of ODEs an algebraic variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-equations, elliptic-curves

**Question: Are the following observations well known, and in what general context?**

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ and consider the following system of differential equations: $$\mathbf{x}'(t)=A\mathbf{x}(t).$$ For a given initial condition $\mathbf{x}(0)$ the (complex) solution is $$\mathcal{V}=\{e^{At}\mathbf{x}(0): t\in\mathbb{C}\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n.$$

Sometimes the set $\mathcal{V}$ is a variety. To see this, let $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$ be a basis of eigenvectors with $A\mathbf{v}_i=\lambda_i\mathbf{v}_i$. Let $V$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with columns $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$ and let $\Lambda$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, so that $$\begin{align} A &=V\Lambda V^{-1}\\ e^{At}&=Ve^{\Lambda t}V^{-1} \\
 e^{At}\mathbf{x}(0) &=Ve^{\Lambda t}V^{-1}\mathbf{x}(0) \\
 \mathbf{x}(t) &=Ve^{\Lambda t}V^{-1}\mathbf{x}(0)\\
 V^{-1}\mathbf{x}(t) &=e^{\Lambda t}V^{-1}\mathbf{x}(0).
\end{align}$$
Let $\mathbf{u}_1^T,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_n^T$ be the rows of $S^{-1}$, i.e., the dual basis of $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$. It follows from the previous equation that $$\mathbf{u}_i^T\mathbf{x}(t)=e^{\lambda_i t} \mathbf{u}_i^T\mathbf{x}(0)$$ for all $i$.

Now we make a special assumption on the eigenvalues of $A$. **Suppose there exist integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $\sum \lambda_ia_i=0$.** Then we have $\prod (e^{\lambda_i t})^{a_i}=e^0=1$, hence the previous equation gives $$\prod (\mathbf{u}_i^T\mathbf{x}(t))^{a_i} = \prod (\mathbf{u}_i^T\mathbf{x}(0))^{a_i}.$$ This shows that for all $t\in\mathbb{C}$, the coordinates of $\mathbf{x}(t)$ satisfy the equation of an algebraic hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Moreover, if the initial condition $\mathbf{x}(0)$ is not an eigenvector (so $\mathbf{u}_i^T\mathbf{x}(0)\neq 0$ for all $i$) then one can use the fact that the vectors $\mathbf{u}_i$ are independent to show that this hypersurface is non-singular. (I'm a bit unclear whether the orbit $\mathcal{V}$ fills up the entire hypersurface.) **Edit: There may be singular points at infinity.**

Example: Consider the system $$\left\{\begin{array}{rl} x'&=y, \\ y'&= 2x+y \end{array}\right. \quad \leadsto\quad \mathbf{x}'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\2&1 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}(t).$$ The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2=-1,2$ with eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1=(1,-1),\mathbf{v}_2=(1,2)$. The dual basis is $\mathbf{u}_1=(2,-1)/3,\mathbf{u}_2=(1,1)/3$. In this case we can take $a_1,a_2=2,1$, so that $2\lambda_1+1\lambda_2=0$. It follows from the above remarks that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ satisfy the equation $$\begin{align} (\mathbf{u}_1^T\mathbf{x}(t))^2(\mathbf{u}_1^T\mathbf{x}(t))^1 &= (\mathbf{u}_1^T\mathbf{x}(0))^2(\mathbf{u}_1^T\mathbf{x}(0))^1\\ (2x(t)-y(t))^2(x(t)+y(t)) &= (2x(0)-y(0))^2(x(0)+y(0))\\ 4x(t)^3-3x(t)y(t)^2+y(t)^3 &= \text{constant}. \end{align}$$ If the initial condition $\mathbf{x}(0)$ is not an eigenvector then the constant is nonzero and we have an elliptic curve. (Again, I am unclear whether the orbit $\mathcal{V}$ fills up the elliptic curve.) **Edit: There is a singular point at infinity, so this is not an elliptic curve.**

Comment: Every solution parameterizes an algebraic variety if and only if all eigenvalues are integer multiples of some number. A single solution can be an algebraic variety if all exponentials which are "present" in it have this property.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Can you give a reference?

Comment: I cannot, but this is easy to prove.